# C# webbrowser control strips URL from # sign and onwards

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

It seems like the webbrowser control's `Navigate(uri)` has a problem with the # character. With a URI like `http://server/path/index.html#ANCHOR?param=value` what is actually transmitted is just the first part, up to (not including) the # character.

Is there any option I should pass to the control to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

what you are trying to do is navigate to an anchor inside the page. basically the `Navigate(uri)` takes you to the page (which is right), and this is why it ignores the part from `#` onwards

if you want to, once in the page, scroll down to the anchor I suggest you to do it using `JavaScript` in the page once it's loaded:

```
document.getElementById(ReceivedId).scrollIntoView(true);
```

of course you'll need to pass the `ReceivedId` to the view from the value that you have in `?param=value`

Comment: I know the hash is the in-page anchor, but it strips all the URL params as well, which the server needs. The ones after ?-sign.

Comment: why are you passing the parameters AND the anchor? is the client side sending you one URL like this somehow (i don't think so)? when you construct the URL, given that you are in the code behind, you can check the existence of this #Anchor and remove it

Comment: I know it's unconventional (stupid). It's the server which wants the URL with the hash. It's an API for a program I'm integrating with made by people w no understanding of Internet standards. I'll give you an up vote, but can't mark your answer as the correct one unfortunately, because what I need is to send the whole URL including all characters to the server (yes that's right) ;(